# Where am I going wrong with this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Good evening to everyone! I got this inequality:
 $$\frac{x-1}{x-2}<\frac{x-1}{x}.$$ If I try to solve this, it gives me $$ \frac{x-1}{x-2}<\frac{x-1}{x} \Rightarrow \frac{x-1}{x-2}-\frac{x-1}{x}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{\left(x-1\right)\left(x-2\right)-x\left(x-1\right)}{x\left(x-2\right)}>0 \Rightarrow \frac{-2\left(x-1\right)}{x\left(x-2\right)}>0 \Rightarrow \left(x-1\right) <0 ; x<1;x>0;x-2>0;x>2.$$ So $x$ belongs to $(-\infty,1)$ and $(2,\infty)$. But the final result is actually $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1,2)$. Where am I going wrong?
Thanks for any response.

Comment: $a > b \implies a - b > 0$. You don't change the sign of the inequality when you move stuff from the LHS to the RHS

Comment: @Ant thanks for the correction:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x-1}{x-2}<\frac{x-1}{x} \implies \frac{x-1}{x-2} - \frac{x-1}{x} > 0$$

is incorrect. The inequality sign should be reversed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you have to do that when moving to LFS

Comment: @T4yl0r You don't, that's the point. When moving it to the LHS you changed the sign, and you shouldn't

Comment: @Ant Oh yeah you're right:)

Answer (score 1):

You got this expression which is correct $\frac{-2(x-1)}{x(x-2)}>0$ which means 
$\frac{(x-1)}{x(x-2)}<0$. You just made mistakes in sign's in intermediate steps but final expression is correct.

Now, arrange $0,1,2$ on number line and find the solution.

SO, final answer is $$x\in (-\infty,0)\cup(0,2)$$

Hope this will be helpful !